# What is the actual difference between scalar and vector quantities?

Tags: vectors

We often differentiate them by saying scalar quantity have magnitude while vector have both direction and magnitude. But how's it possible that if an object is moving then it won't have direction in case of scalar quantity?

Comment: how about reading about  scalars  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_(physics)  and vectors? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_(mathematics_and_physics)

Comment: Just think about velocity vs. speed.

Comment: Because I can just say I'm moving at 60mi/hr and give no direction whatsoever, and that's a statement about my speed...not my velocity

Comment: Re, "...how's it possible that if an object is moving then...?" You're going to have to decide whether your question is about vectors and scalars or, about moving objects. The relationship between vectors and scalars is not defined by how objects move. It has a strictly mathematical definition. Here's my favorite intro to the subject: https://www.amazon.com/Linear-Algebra-Right-Undergraduate-Mathematics/dp/0387982582

Comment: Be aware that scalars and vectors mean different things in different contexts.

Comment: "*But how's it possible that if an object is moving then it won't have direction*" Who says it doesn't have direction? Can I not talk about speed, without having to consider direction? The police officer doesn't care much about the direction, when he fines you for speeding. When direction isn't relevant, then we can choose to consider only the "amount" - the magnitude - to not make it harder for ourselves.

Comment: https://www.physicskey.com/4/what-is-the-difference-between-scalars-and-vectors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But how's it possible that if an object is moving then it won't have
>   direction in case of scalar quantity?

A scalar quantity is simply a number. But a scalar quantity can be associated with a vector quantity. In such cases the scalar quantity is the magnitude of the vector.

If you are driving a car the speedometer gives you its speed (mph or kph). But if you are only looking at the speedometer and not the road (and you shouldn't!) it would only be a number. It's only when you look at the road (or perhaps your Nav) when you can then determine the direction of the car, and when you are able to associate the  speedometer reading with the velocity of the car, i.e., the magnitude of its velocity.

But not all scalar quantities are the magnitudes of vectors. Examples are time, mass, energy, and temperature to name a very few.

Hope this helps.